# Get the TabItem Name or header if it has validation Error

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, mvvm

I have the following TabConrol

```
<telerik:RadTabControl 
        Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
            DisplayMemberPath="Content" DropDownDisplayMode="Visible" ScrollMode="Item" BorderThickness="0">
        <telerik:RadTabItem DropDownContent="Job Config" Header="Job Config" >
            <telerik:RadTabItem.Content>
                <ScrollViewer  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                    <local:JobGroupsCars DataContext="{Binding}" Margin="10" IsEnabled="{Binding Job.IsNotInEditMode ,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                </ScrollViewer>
            </telerik:RadTabItem.Content>
        </telerik:RadTabItem>
        <telerik:RadTabItem 
            DropDownContent="Job Info" Header="Job Info" >
            <telerik:RadTabItem.Content>
                <ScrollViewer  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                    <local:JobDetailView DataContext="{Binding}" Margin="10" IsEnabled="{Binding Job.IsNotInEditMode ,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </telerik:RadTabItem.Content>
        </telerik:RadTabItem>

    <-- more tabs go here -->

    </telerik:RadTabControl>
```

As you can see, the TabItem is a user control
What Im trying to achieve is when I click the save button I want to show the name that has validation errors

Im able to get all the validation errors but Im not able to show which tab has this error (as you can see in the below image)

[image: validation errors]

I tried to use the following snippet but its not working

```
<UserControl.Resources>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ValidationTabTemplate">

        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">

            <Image Width="32" Height="32"

                   Source="../Assets/Delete_Icon.png" Opacity="0.75"

                   ToolTip="{Binding Path=AdornedElement.ToolTip, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Adorner}, Mode=FindAncestor}}"

            />

            <AdornedElementPlaceholder/>

        </DockPanel>

    </ControlTemplate>
    <Style x:Key="CustomTabError" TargetType="{x:Type telerik:RadTabItem}">

        <Style.Triggers>

            <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">

                <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate"

                            Value="{StaticResource ValidationTabTemplate}"/>


            </Trigger>

        </Style.Triggers>

    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

I am using WPF with MVVM

Any help would be appreciated
thanks alot

Comment: You could access the  field that contains the error and itterate to its parents until you hit the actual tab control

Comment: Alternativly which is properly the better solution use a multibinding and bind your tabcontrol to all controls it contains.Validation.HasError propertys 
in your MultiValueConverter check if they are good else Highlight the Tabcontrol to show the error

Comment: thanks for your quick reply but can you please give a little bit of code snippet , thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Okay a little more detailed than my comment:
You want to highight the Tabcontrol that containes your error if i understand you correctly:
Imagine this beeing your tabcontrol and the Checkboxes beeing your input fields we bound our tab item to each of our checkboxes.IsChecked via Multibinding 
this would be your custom control and the .Validation.HasError property

if any of the CheckBoxes is not checked ( or in your case if an error occoured) the forground of the tabcontrol will become red by using a  multiconverter

```
  <TabControl>
    <TabItem Header="Test">
        <TabItem.Foreground>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiEval}">
                <Binding  ElementName="CB1" Path="IsChecked"/>
                <Binding  ElementName="CB2" Path="IsChecked"/>
                <Binding  ElementName="CB3" Path="IsChecked"/>

            </MultiBinding>            
        </TabItem.Foreground>
        <StackPanel>                
            <CheckBox Name="CB1"></CheckBox>
            <CheckBox Name="CB2"></CheckBox>
            <CheckBox Name="CB3"></CheckBox>

        </StackPanel>
    </TabItem>

<Window.Resources>
    <loc:MultiEvaluator x:Key="MultiEval"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

Converter:

```
public class MultiEvaluator : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        foreach (var value in values)
        {
            if (!System.Convert.ToBoolean(value))
            {
                return Brushes.Red;
            }
        }
        return Brushes.Black;
    } 

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

}
```